# Append jquery object to formData()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm currently developing a back office for some website, and I've come across some problems with file and information insert into databases. First I cannot upload a file and information in the same form without having to declare a variable for every other input, and second cannot append the declared object, like I always do, to the upload file form.

I've tried appending as and object but some of the inputs get undefined indexes.

This is the code i tried, to append an object to formData():

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#addinfo-form').submit(function(e) {
  var info = {
   'name':$('#name').val(),
   'email':$('#email').val(),
   'country':$('#country :selected').val()
  }
  var file = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
  var new_info = new formData();
  new_info.append('info', info);
  new_info.append('file', file;
  $.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'add-info.php',
   data:new_info,
   dataType:'json',
   processData:false,
   contentType:false,
   encode:true,
  }
  .done(function(data) {
  })
  .fail(function(data) {
  });
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

Expected outcome should send info to php file via json to then be processed and inserted in the database.

Comment: Have you try new_info.set('info', info) ?

Comment: instead of appending it?

Comment: to send file see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57660844/2776343

Comment: responseText: "<br />\n<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: location in <b>C:\\wamp64\\www\\dfrango\\administrator\\assets\\functions\\gallery\\add-gallery.php</b> on line <b>10</b><br />\n{\"success\":false,\"errors\":{\"name\":\"Por favor preencha os campos obrigat\\u00f3rios.\"}}"

Comment: seem that you don't send "location" variable

Comment: what are required variables in add-info.php?

Comment: but i do, is the select element that is f*cking my code... is there other way to get the selected option?

Comment: $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'] and $_POST['country'], for now, while im trying to figure this out.

Comment: if is a select try to use $('#country).val()

Comment: doesn't work... same error, undefined index

Comment: Ah sorry you are using two objects, but submit only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var info = {
    'name': $('#name').val(),
    'email': $('#email').val(),
    'country': $('#country').val()
};

var file = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
var new_info = new FormData();
new_info.append("file", file, file.name);
new_info.append("info", JSON.stringify(info));

$.ajax({
type:'POST',
        url:'add-info.php',
        data:new_info,
        dataType:'json',
        processData:false,
        contentType:false,
        encode:true,
 /*....*/
```

in your add-info.php

```
if (isset($_POST['info'])) {
    $info = json_decode($_POST['info'], true);
    echo $info["name"];
    echo $info["email"];
    echo $info["country"];
}
```

Comment: that kinda defeats the purpose of the object, I know that if i define every variable like that it does work, that's why i'm trying with an object

Comment: @andrejmonteiro1996 Is that what you wanted?

Comment: i guess so, it works, let me apply it to the rest of the code, thank you <3

Comment: You're welcome @andrejmonteiro1996! Are you talking about file upload?

Comment: works perfectly, i can now upload files with info, to add to the database

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `Object.entries()` such that your code now becomes...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#addinfo-form').submit(function(e) {
  var file = $('#file').prop('files')[0];
  var info = {
   'name':$('#name').val(),
   'email':$('#email').val(),
   'country':$('#country :selected').val(),
   'file': file
  }
  var new_info = new formData();
  Object.entries(info).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    new_info.append(key, value);
  });
  $.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url:'add-info.php',
   data:new_info,
   dataType:'json',
   processData:false,
   contentType:false,
   encode:true,
  }
  .done(function(data) {
  })
  .fail(function(data) {
  });
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

You first grab the file, add it as a property to your `info` object and parse it to `formData`.

Comment: I use the same method to insert big queries onto a database